# Access private instance from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-networking

We host our bitbucket on a dedicated server on EC2. The server is accessible to us via VPN (OpenVPN).

I am trying to export a branch from Bitbucket using Lambda so I can save it to a s3 bucket to be used by a pipeline.

My problem is the Lambda can't access the server (because it is only available via VPN).

I'm using the [AWS code pipeline bitbucket integration](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-codepipeline-bitbucket-integration) but Lambda can't access the server when it is attached to the VPC and when it is not.

I'm looking a solution which will allow the Lambda to reach the server "from" the VPN.

(We have a host name + SSL certificate so I can't call the IP directly)

Thank you!

Comment: Normally SSM Run Command would be used for that. Have you considered that?

Comment: By default whenever a lambda function is created it is created outside our vpc (internally in Amazon's vpc) which means lambda cannot access resource inside our vpc.

In order to make sure your lambda can access resources inside your vpc, it needs to be added in private subnet with proper route tables and permission to create ENI interface role name AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: After attaching Lambda to the VPC, did you open the security group on the EC2 server to allow Lambda to connect? I assume when you say you tried attaching it to the same VPC that the EC2 instance is in?